# how convert string to array "a,b,c" => "a","b","c"?

Tags: javascript

Hello, how convert my string let = "a,b,c"; to "a","b","c"

Example:

```
let lang = "a,b,c";
// Convert ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the string using the comma (`,`) string:

```js
let lang = "a,b,c";
console.log(lang.split(','));
```